# Filter a javascript array with another array

Tags: javascript, filtering

How can I filter a javascript object using an array? For example, I have an array called `arr1`:

```js
arr1 = [
 {"id":"A0001", "user":"asdf"},
 {"id":"A0002", "user":"fgh"},
 {"id":"A0122", "user":"fegr"}, 
 {"id":"B0003","user":"dff"},
 {"id":"B1567", "user":"asdf"},
 {"id":"C0012", "user":"dwdw"}
]
```

and I perform a search with `arr2 = ['A0', 'B0', 'A00']`

I've tried using filter and indexOf.

```js
arr2.forEach(element =>{ 
  console.log(arr1.filter(function(el){
    return el.id.indexOf(element) !== -1
  }))
})
```

It should return:

```js
[
 {"id":"A0001", "user":"asdf"}, 
 {"id": "A0002", "user":"fgh"},
 {"id":"A0122", "user":"fegr"},
 {"id": "B0003","user":"dff"}
]
```

But it returns:

```js
[
 {id:'A0001', user:'asdf' },
 {id:'A0002', user:'fgh' },
 {id:'A0122', user:'fegr' } 
]
[ 
 {id:'B0003', user:'dff' } ]
[
 {id:'A0001', user:'asdf' }, 
 {id:'A0002', user:'fgh' } 
]
```

Comment: would you mind specifying which one is laptopList and which one is laptopInput? Also, the filter method returns a new array, so this is somewhat expected behavior since you are running it on each element.

Comment: sorry about that forgot to change the variables. laptopInput is arr2 and laptoplist is arr1. I did want an array but I wanted one long one which doesn't repeat the ones already there (not necessarily unique id but the same id and user)

Comment: `list.filter(x => search.some(y => x.id.includes(y))`